# How can I make multi-language program with C++

Tags: c++, string, multilingual

I want to create multi-language feature for C++ program which would be similar to Android.

I have file language.xml and language-us.xml, if user's language is US then lang_variable is searching in language-us.xml, if didn't found then use keyword in language.xml . In code I would like to access lang-variables something like: R.string.lang_variable.

Language files can be not xml, i just want to make multi-language.

Thanks, for answer !

Comment: Voting to close question because it is too broad.

Comment: The best method is to use table lookups.  You could convert the table system into OOD, but IMO, not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done by using lookup tables.

Any phrase that needs translation is assigned an ID value.

There is a table of `ID vs. text` for every language, can be as simple as an array of text.

Each supported language has an ID.  There is one table of *language ID vs. Language Table* for every supported language.

So, first take the language ID and get the translation table for the given language.
Next, use the phrase or text ID to get the phrase from the language table.

This doesn't really have anything to do with the C++ language.

Also, use a character type that can support all required encodings, such as multibyte or Unicode.

**Edit 1: Spreadsheets**
We use a spreadsheet that contains the language ID (first column) and the translated text in different languages (each language is a separate column).  We then have a custom application that converts the spreadsheet into appropriate tables (as discussed above).